# Java: Appending data to JSON and finding data from it

Tags: java, json, get, extract, put

Hi all! I've been trying to solve this for hours now. One of my last assignments is to add JSON data manipulation to my Java program and we have been taught 0 information about it so I'm doing this with very little JSON knowledge. I need to make it so my program can 1) write and store user information in a JSON file and 2) filter through said JSON file to retrieve information.

I've made a bit of progress, but I've hit a wall. Here is the method that writes to the JSON file:

```
    public void createUser(String username, String password) {
    profileObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    // Put values into JSON
    profileObj.put("username", username);
    profileObj.put("password", password);

    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("data.json", true)) {

        file.append(profileObj.toJSONString());
        file.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I run the program and create 3 profiles, the JSON file will look like this:

```
{"password":"pass","username":"one"}
{"password":"pass","username":"two"}
{"password":"pass","username":"three"}
```

After doing a lot of research, I'm not sure if that is a proper format to read JSON with. I also have no idea how to create a method to filter through JSON code to find a specific String value. I had this method originally:

```
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    profileObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("data.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject userObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("users");

        String usernameField = (String) jsonObject.get("username");
        String passwordField = (String) jsonObject.get("password");
        System.out.println(usernameField + " " + passwordField);
        System.out.println(username + " " + password);

        if (username.equals(usernameField) && password.equals(passwordField))
            return true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

However that method only work when the JSON file has 1 user and password in it. It cannot read multiple sets.

The end goal is to have a readable JSON file and a method that can search for a key value (i.e. a specific username or password).

I've been searching on the internet and debugging for hours now. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Google Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson) in combination with POJO `User` object:

```
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final String filename = "data.json";

private class User {
    String username;
    String password;
    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Methods would look like this:

```
public void addUser(String username, String password) {
    try {
        List<User> users = readUsers(filename);
        users.add(new User(username, password));
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, false));
        gson.toJson(users, writer);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    try {
        List<User> users = readUsers(filename);
        return users.stream().anyMatch(user -> username.equals(user.username) && password.equals(user.password));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private List<User> readUsers(String filename) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    List<User> users = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType());
    reader.close();
    return users == null ? new ArrayList<>() : users;
}
```